# Align text next to input element

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align text next to a an imput element. An example image to show, how I want it to look like. The text is supposed to be in the red box. The crossed out part should be empty.

[image]

My code for a minimal example:
https://jsfiddle.net/5m0yjus7/

**HTML**

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="group">
        <label>Label1</label>
        <input name="title" type="text" value="Something">
        <span class="infotext">Lorem ipsum bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla</span>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <label>Label2</label>
        <input name="title" type="text" value="Something2">
        <span class="infotext">Some infotext</span>
    </div>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
label {
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
.group {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.infotext {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this very easily using [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).

Use `display: flex;` in place of `display: block;` on parent element.

Something like below:

```css
label {
  float: left;
  display: block;
}

.group {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

input {
  height: 20px;
}

.infotext {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<form method="post">
    <div class="group">
        <label>Label1</label>
        <input name="title" type="text" value="Something">
    <span class="infotext">Lorem ipsum bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla</span>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
      <label>Label2</label>
        <input name="title" type="text" value="Something2">
    <span class="infotext">Some infotext</span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

These are following css i have changed:

```
.infotext {
  display: inline-block;
  width:50%;
}
input{
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```css
label {
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
.group {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.infotext {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}
input {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<form method="post">
  <div class="group">
    <label>Label1</label>
    <input name="title" type="text" value="Something">
    <span class="infotext">Lorem ipsum bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla</span>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <label>Label2</label>
    <input name="title" type="text" value="Something2">
    <span class="infotext">Some infotext</span>
  </div>
</form>
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/r8tfjqq7/)

Answer (score 1):

Use **display: inline-block;** on both elements or set vertical align top if ye have set height or line-height and want to set it in middle so make it vertical align middle.

```
input {display:inline-block;height:40px;}
.className {
    display:inline-block;
    height:40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just make this code to class infotext:

```css
.infotext {
  display: inline;
}
```

```css
label {
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
.group {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.infotext {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<form method="post">
 <div class="group">
  <label>Label1</label>
  <input name="title" type="text" value="Something">
    <span class="infotext">Lorem ipsum bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla</span>
 </div>
 <div class="group">
   <label>Label2</label>
  <input name="title" type="text" value="Something2">
    <span class="infotext">Some infotext</span>
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Well no, the beginning of the next line is not supposed to be below the input field, but on the right side, below the "Lorem"